# The std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator exception

Tags: c++, windows-10, c++17

The following function:

```
void foo(const std::string& dir)
{
    for (auto& el : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(dir)) {
            std::cout << el.path() << '\n';
    }
}
```

when used in:

```
int main()
{
    std::string p = "C:\\";
    foo(p);
}
```

raises an exception when it reaches a certain folder (I assume) on Windows 10. The code is compiled on VS 2017 with C++17 support. 
The exception message is:

```
recursive_directory_iterator::operator++: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

The same behavior occurs when using the `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` too.
Why is it raising an exception on that particular folder?

Comment: You have a *Documents and Settings* folder in Windows 10?

Comment: Agreed it should be `Users` with that said I suspect this is a permissions problem since a normal user does not have the rights to traverse the children of such a folder.

Comment: If Windows 10 was upgraded from Windows 7, could be a leftover junction point.

Comment: @Eljay Windows 7 also has a user folder.  IIRC Windows XP was the last to have a *Documents and Settings* folder.

Comment: @NathanOliver • XP had a Documents and Settings folder.  Windows 7 used a junction point for backwards compatibility with XP-era applications.  (How come no one speaks of Vista anymore?  lol)

Comment: FWIW, I also got an exception, different folder than you most likely but: `Unhandled exception at 0x7720DDC2 in Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::filesystem::filesystem_error at memory location 0x00F9F63C. occurred`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Indeed. I have updated the question.

Comment: @drescherjm I tried the "Run As Administrator" to no avail. The exception persists.

Comment: @drescherjm I agree with you. Must be some privileges issue.  I can confirm I can't iterate through the entire _Windows _folder while I can through  _Program Files (x86)_

Answer (score 9):

Apparently, exception is raised when the OS denies a permission to access one of the folders.

The workaround is to utilize the appropriate [recursive directory iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/recursive_directory_iterator) constructor overload (4th one) and supply the [`skip_permission_denied`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_options) parameter:

```
for (auto& el : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(dir, std::filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied)) {
    std::cout << el.path() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Sadly, `fs::recursive_directory_iterator(".",
                       fs::directory_options::follow_directory_symlink
   | fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied)` can still crash with the same exception e.g. on non-native filesystems (like ext2) with filenames that contain chars invalid to the native Windows API.

Comment: That's not enough. For instance "C:\PerfLogs" is 777, but the system does not allow a normal user to see its content. It seems there is another level of "permissions" with NTFS / Windows.

Comment: Nice try, but definitely not enough. The folder that stops my iteration is `C:\Users\bozo\AppData\Local\Application Data`. Explorer hides this "Application Data" in Win11. Git Bash reveals it is a symlink, to `C:\Users\bozo\AppData\Local`. I'm using MSYS2 and `g++`, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error on Windows 10 on a folder entry.

The entry was corrupt and it was not possible to read or delete that folder in windows at all.
I could however rename the folder, but in the end I had to wipe the hard drive because not even Windows (or any commands/repair tools) could fix the issue.

So in my case I would say that it was an appropriate exception (as expected).