# Having a issue while iterating all files and folders recursively in C++

Tags: c++, loops

I have the following code to iterate all the files and folders on all the drives on a system. Can you help me please understand what is missing ? I'm getting an exception for fs::recursive_directory_iterator. Thanks !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;


std::vector<std::string> getDrive() {
    std::vector<std::string> Drives;
    char* lDrives = new char[MAX_PATH]();
    if (GetLogicalDriveStringsA(MAX_PATH, lDrives))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 4)
        {
            if (lDrives[i] != (char)0)
            {
                Drives.push_back(std::string{ lDrives[i],lDrives[i + 1],lDrives[i + 2] });
            }          
        }
    }
    delete[] lDrives;
    return Drives;

}
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> diskdrives = getDrive();

    for (auto drv : diskdrives) {
        for (auto& file : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(drv)) {
            try {
                if (fs::is_directory(file))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << file.path().string() << std::endl;
                }
            }
            catch (const std::exception&)
            {

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, where exactly did your debugger show your exception getting thrown from?

Comment: Why do you ignore the return value of `GetLogicalDriveStringsA` (which should return you the length of the buffer), but iterate `[0: 100: 4]`? What are the contents of the `Drives` after that? I guess that the contents are not what you expect.

Comment: Almost every line of the `getDrive()` function is bad coding style or an outright error.  Why are you using dynamic allocation for a fixed-size buffer?  Why are you manually freeing when there is `std::unique_ptr`?  Why are you advancing by 4 characters, instead of the size of whatever was found in the previous location?

Comment: For debugging purposes, get rid of `getDrives()` and just fill the vector in `main` with known drives you are using, as `getDrives()` just clutters everything.  Do you still get the error?

Comment: If you had not introduced `getDrives` and wrote a simple `main` function, then possibly you would have discovered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318249/the-stdfilesystemrecursive-directory-iterator-exception) to see if it is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Tip: Don't use `new char[]`, use `std::string`. If you need a temporary character buffer just use `char[N]` so you're absolutely certain it properly gets disposed of.

Comment: @Aorta2k It would be helpful if you would show what the exception actually says